# Remove some, but not all overloaded functions inherited from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I am writing a vector class that takes ownership of member pointers. As far as possible, I want to reuse std:vector. I have been trying private and public inheritance; in both cases I am running into difficulties.

For private inheritance, see issue [how to write forward iterator using private std::vector base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72247817).

For public inheritance, I need to delete certain methods from the base class. Specifically, I need to prevent users from replacing member pointers without deleting objects. So I want to delete `T* & operator[](int i)`. At the same time, I still want to support `T* const operator[](int i) const`. Somehow, the deletion of the former seems to overrule the reimplementation of the latter. Here a minimal complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

/* Vector class that takes ownership of member pointers */
template <class T>
class OwningVector : public std::vector<T*> {
    using super = std::vector<T*>;

public:
    ~OwningVector() { /* deletes objects pointed to */ };

    T* & operator[](int i) = delete;
    T* const operator[](int i) const { return super::operator[](i); }
};

class A {
public:
    A(int m) : m(m) {}
    int m;
};

int main() {
    OwningVector<A> v;
    v.emplace_back(new A(1));
    std::cout << v[0]->m << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation fails:

```
hh.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hh.cpp:23:21: error: use of deleted function ‘T*& OwningVector<T>::operator[](int) [with T = A]’
   23 |     std::cout << v[0]->m << std::endl;
      |                     ^
hh.cpp:9:10: note: declared here
    9 |     T* & operator[](int i) = delete;
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Don't inherit from `std` containers, use them internally exposing your own interface

Comment: 1. You cannot delete base class member functions only "hide them". 2. Don't inherit from `std containers`. Instead of inheritance, just keep a vector inside your class as a member and define the interface for it.

Comment: The alternate problem, with private inheritance from std::vector, has been solved in the meantime, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72247817.

Comment: Nonetheless, I leave this one open, hoping for some more insight in the problem of `= delete` vs overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments:*

Using `v[0]->m` will call the const-version of the operator if `v` is const. Otherwise it calls the non-const operator.

The fact that you don't write to `v` doesn't affect this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to re-invent the wheel. All you need is a vector of smart pointers:

```
template <class T>
using OwningVector = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
```

Comment: You're making some assumptions of OP use case, but that's a good point

Comment: Actually I have to move away from `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` because they are unsupported under pybind11.

Comment: Furthermore, my class will be copyable, which `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is not.